# Algorithm for pool ball movement calcualtion

Tags: c, algorithm

I need help or idea how to make an algorithm for a pool game/program.

I need this as a project for my collage so this needs to be written as simply as possible using only basic and loops,sadly I can't use arrays or functions.

The whole point of the program is to calculate how many steps/hits on the corner of the table will the ball need to reach its starting point (Assumed that ball has infinite velocity and that there are no other balls etc.. Simply we assume that its possible)

We need to look at the table as a coordinate system with (m x n) dimensions, and we need to input starting point of the ball (x1,y1) and the point where the ball will hit the table for the first time (x2,y2) based on that info we need to make an algorithm that will calculate how many hits/steps will the ball need to reach its starting point.

I had an idea to use the fact that ball will have same angle on impact which means that if the ball hits the table on 30 degrees angle it will repel off the table with same angle to the other side. So because the tables is set as a coordinate system I could use atan to calculate the angle and then with that info to calculate the distance from the other point. I made a program with the info I know but this won't work because this is only one calculation (I guess that I will need to use for loop(s) to calculate everything. And I have a big problem in understanding how to set the edge of the table because some of my calculations goes outside the (m x n) space.

I will attach 2 pictures that were given to us as examples and part of the code that I use. I hope that someone can help me and I'm sorry if I made a lot of grammar mistakes, English is not my primary language.

Thanks in advance.

PICTURES :

Orange dot is the starting point, orange line is the first hit that we input,everything else needs to be calculated:

[image: Orange dot is the starting point, orange line is the first hit that we input,everything else needs to be calculated]

Same as picture one but more complex example:

[image: Same as picture one but more complex example]

MY CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265359

int main() {

    int i;
    double x1,y1,x2,y2;
    int n,m;
    double angle;
    double xPrime,yPrime;
    double distance;
    double m1;


    printf("Enter the staring point (x1,y1) and first hit point(x2,y2) ");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
    printf("Enter the dimensions (n x m ) ");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);


        m1=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
        angle=atan(m1);

        distance =sqrt( pow((x2-x1),2) + pow((y2-y1),2));

        xPrim = x2 + (-distanca * cos(ugao));
        yPrim = y2 + (distanca * sin(ugao));




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not want to *enter* the hit-point, but **calculate** it, from the start-point and a given angle, won't you? So for all other coming hit-points.

Comment: Then find the point the line it goes crosses the tables border (which is the hit-point), then calculate the new angle and start over.

Comment: are the given coordinates integers?

Comment: Hello,
Fist of all: position (x,y) is given as integer or real number? You used double as if real. And it produces a big problem with  "reach its starting point" - how preciselly. However i think you should use integers and round coordinates of wall hit.

Comment: Yes the input number is always integer but in example number 2 there are points where that dot is between two coordinates.

Comment: Hint: instead of calculating the reflections, you can consider mirror copies of the table so that it covers the whole plane and consider the path a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the X and Y axes separately.  The discussion below assumes that the ball initially starts moving in the positive direction on both axes. If it doesn't then flip stuff around to the symmetrical situation so that it does.

Given the table size by **M x N**, the starting point **(x0,y0)**, and the first hit **(x1,y1)**:

Let **T** be the time it takes to get from **(x0,y0)** to **(x1,y1)**, so the initial velocity (in units per T) is **(vx,vy) = (x1-x0, y1-y0)**

Considering the X axis, the ball will hit a wall at time **(M-x0)/vx**, measured in units of **T**.  It will get back to the starting **X** coordinate at time **(2M-2x0)/vx**.  It will hit the other wall at time **(2M-x0)/vx** and get back to the start position again at time **2M/vx**.  Then the cycle will repeat.

So, the times at which it will get back to the start position are **(2aM - 2x0)/vx** and **2aM/vx**, for all integer **a>0**.  The times it will hit a wall are **(2aM - x0)** and **((2a-1)M - x0)**.

Similarly, on the **Y** axis, the times it will get back to the start position are **(2bN - 2y0)/vy** and **2bN/vy**, for all integer **b>0**.  The times it will hit a wall are **(2bN - y0)** and **((2b-1)N - y0)**.

So, to find times when the ball gets back to the start, solve:

- **(2aM - 2x0)/vx = (2bN - 2y0)/vy** or
- **(2aM - 2x0)/vx = 2bN/vy** or
- **2aM/vx = (2bN - 2y0)/vy** or
- **2aM/vx = 2bN/vy**

for the smallest integers **a>0** and **b>0**.

All of these reduce to linear Diophantine equations that are readily solved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Once you know how long it takes to get back to the start, you can use the other equations above to calculate how many wall hits  were made.